# Creating an md5sum via Automator without filename in destination file

Tags: bash, md5, automator

I’m using Automator to pull files from a folder and generate an md5 for each. This is all working but I don’t know how to only write the md5 itself to the destination file without the source file path.

```
for f in “@“
do
    echo “$f”
    md5 “$f” > “$f”.md5
done
```

This resulting file includes both.

Comment: Btw.: Replace all `”` with `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help with your loop to get only first column:

```
md5 "$f" | awk '{print $1}' > "$f".md5
```

Or only with `bash`:

```
md5 "$f" | while read -r sum foo; do echo "$sum"; done > "$f".md5
```

Comment: First one worked! Just changed the `$1` to `$4`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Okay, that's where the output differs significantly from my `md5sum`. This might help with second example: Replace `sum foo` with `foo foo foo sum foo`.